# Magento 2.4 How to activate the auto refresh for orders, so when customer place order directly it appear in the orders grid with out manual refresh?

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, order-management

How to activate the auto refresh for orders, so when customer place order directly it appear in the orders grid (Order management - Admin backend) with out manual refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Check if asynchronous indexing is enabled

```
bin/magento config:show dev/grid/async_indexing
```

If it is enabled updates are handled by cron job called  **sales_grid_order_async_insert**

Comment: He’s asking for auto-reloading the grid , this answer doesn’t apply.